# x86_64 Assembly Segmentation Fault when trying to add value

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a segmentation fault error immediately after I use an addq instruction; the code is fine before I implement the instruction.

```
.data
insn_count:
    .long 0
str:
    .string "test"

bubble_sort:
.LFB2:
 addq $3,insn_count
.cfi_startproc
pushq %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
movq %rdi, -24(%rbp)
movl %esi, -28(%rbp)
movl $0, -4(%rbp)
jmp .L2
```

That's a sample portion of my code. I can't seem to pinpoint what the issue is; can anyone help? I have also tried defining insn_count using the .long directive but I still get the same error.

Comment: You're right, I meant to assign memory to insn_count. I replaced it with .long 0 and also placed the .data directive before the definitions. I still continue to get the same error though. I am testing assigning variables via assembly and editing them with instrumentation code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this assembly syntax, but seems, that "addq $3,insn_count" is trying to add 3 to address of insn_count not to it's value. Because of that you could have segmentation fault.